# Navigation Drawer Interactiong with MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, navigation-drawer

I'm using the Google Maps API V2 for Android and I was wondering if the new Navigation Drawer from Google could interact with a MapFragement.
In the drawer there would be a list of waypoints and when the user click on it the map will center on the clicked waypoint.

Sorry for the english and Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it's possible. For one of my projects I don't use it for this but here is approach. I used SherlockMapFragment (for better compatibility) but it works same with MapFragment

```
class DrawerItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
         case 0:
            SherlockMapFragment someFragment= new FragmentSome();
            Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
            args1.putInt("index", DATA_SLEEP); // here put some data
            someFragment.setArguments(args1);
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentFrame, someFragment)
                    .commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("I am fragment");
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
            break;
```

Then on fragment on create catch the new map that is instanced by map fragment store it in a view, add it to inflated layout and get reference to it with gmap = getMap() then use gmap which is map object :

```
    public class FragmentSome extends SherlockMapFragment{
private GoogleMap gMap;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        private View mapView;
        mapView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); //

sore map in a view 
            initType = getArguments().getInt("index");
            loadData();
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food_sleep, container, false);
        }

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        FrameLayout mapHolder = (FrameLayout) getView().findViewById(
                R.id.mapContainer);
        mapHolder.addView(mapView); // add map to inflated layout

            gMap = getMap(); // get reference to map and from here do whatever...

        if (initType == MainActivity.DATA_FOOD) {
            gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                    46.390752, 16.437006), 5));
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
        } else {
            gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                    46.388322, 16.427994), 5));
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13), 2000, null);
        }


        }
```